# Netbeans often used code snippets

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

i need this:

```
{{ _('') }}
```

very often and get tired by typing it again over and over.

Is there a netbeans function where i can create a shortcode for that? Si if i press a key combination it insert this thing?

And i dont want to use copy and paste ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is. If you go to `tools` --> `options` --> `Editor` --> `Code Templates`, you can add a abbreviation and the Expanded text to make it.

For example, when I type `syso` and hit the Tab button, it makes it `System.out.println("${cursor}");`, where the cursor is at `${cursor}`.

Comment: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html covers it in detail. It's for PHP, but I think it makes no difference.

Comment: Exactly. I did this from the top of my head, that website probably explains it better and more detailed.

Comment: Thanks thats weird. For php it works. but if i try using it on twig (twig template selected) then it simply does nothing. any idea why?

Comment: Found a solution. Just need to add it to html templates. Its a old bug. Thanks guys :)